# I am receiving status 401 Unauthorized when I attempt to call my secured API by keycloak

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0, keycloak, http-status-code-401

I have an web application providing an REST API endpoints, secured with spring security and SSO Keycloak.

My web application works fine with protection on and I can access REST API endpoints using web browser, after authentication on keycloak and redirect back to endpoint. I am getting expected JSON response, which mean user and role should be configured correctly.

But when i want to call a provided REST API endpoint from another web application or using Postman, i have every time an error 401 error: unauthorized.

In the header of the request I am putting:
"Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgO...." token.

I am able to fetch this token from keycloak in consumer web application and also when I am making a request using postman.

My Keycloak configuration in my spring security config:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class KeycloakSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    /**
     * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/app/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

My **keycloak.json** file:

```
{
    "realm": "realm-name",
    "auth-server-url": "https://auth.server.com/auth/",
    "ssl-required": "external",
    "resource": "resource-name",
    "verify-token-audience": true,
    "credentials": {
        "secret": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
    "confidential-port": 0
}
```

My method in the controller of the api:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class WakeMeUpController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String testMeUp() {
        return "I am tested!";
    }
}
```

This is a part of my client configuration in keycloak:
[keycloak Client screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LAVl.png)

Rest keycloak config is how it is coming by default.

Thx for your help!

Comment: Add this to your app properties: `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` and paste your log output after getting 401.

Comment: Thank you! That give me a light in the issue and I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. The problem was into audience configuration in keycloak.

For a client, you need to configure new Mapping under Client -> <client_name> -> Mappers and add another Mapping with mapper type 'Audience' and appropriate 'Included Client audience' (i choose client id i have used to make request)

Also another problem that i have faced after i solve this one, was that user was authenticated but was forbidden the access to endpoint.
Explicitly adding role into client configuration itself and assigning this role to the user solve it and it is working.

From huge help was setting spring logging to DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

And also XXX-Authentication header in server response that gives better description what the issue is.

Comment: Your fixes were required because of `"verify-token-audience": true` and `"use-resource-role-mappings": true` settings. First is responsible for checking `aud` jwt claim for containing your `<client-id>`. Second setting is responsible for resolving your user roles based on `resource_access.<client-id>.roles` jwt claim. Both settings are recommended in adapter configuration for security reasons.